# Open Graph protocol code for Blogger and get the Post's Body

Tags: blogger

I'm inserting on my blogger blog the code, such that it can create automatically  [the Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) snippets used, for example, by many social media websites.

I see many source code around, but none seems to work perfectly.

I wrote this, which I inserted right before tag `</head>` in the blogger template. It's working nice except on the property `og:description`. I'd like also to have the post content as description.

```html
<!-- OpenGraph starts-->
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>

<!-- Title and URL -->
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl.https' property='og:url'/>

<!--Description-->
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
<b:elseif cond='data:post.snippet'/>
    <meta expr:content='data:post.snippet' property='og:description'/>
<b:else/>
    <meta expr:content='data:I_WANT_THE_POST_BODY' property='og:description'/>
</b:if>

<!-- Image -->
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:elseif cond='data:blog.postImageUrl'/>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>    
<b:else/>
    <meta content='MY_BLOG_LOGO_URL' property='og:image'/> 
</b:if>

<meta expr:content='data:blog.locale' property='og:locale'/>

<!-- OpenGraph ends-->
```

My problem is that I can't really get the post Body, and as stated in [documentation](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en), that is `posts.body`.

**Which is the `data` variable to get the body/content of the current/viewed/available post?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only one way to use description meta-tags - inside of `<b:includable id='post' var='post'>...</b:if>`.

For example:

```html
<b:includable id='post' var='post'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item" or data:blog.pageType == "static_page"'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription != ""'>
      <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='twitter:description'/>
      <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
    <b:else/>
      <meta expr:content='data:post.snippet' name='twitter:description'/>
      <meta expr:content='data:post.snippet' property='og:description'/>
    </b:if>
  </b:if>
  ...Other code...
</b:includable>
```

Also, you can use `<meta expr:content='data:blog.locale' property='og:locale'/>` for language tag.

Comment: Thanks! where do you recommend me to insert that code, in `<head>` or in `<body>`?

Comment: Just after `<b:includable id='post' var='post'>` tag in your template (otherwise, it will not work).

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, because all the code around the web is saying to insert that code right before `</head>`

Comment: Thanks also for tip `data:blog.locale`. I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Implanting open graph within `body` tag is invalid and not the right thing to do. meta tags should be within `head` tag. also Facebook won't consider it in `body`.
please refer to these links:

- [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)
- [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element)
- [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/#metadata)

you can use `data:view.description` instead to get a snippet of each post within `head` tag.

```
<!-- Description -->
<meta expr:content='data:view.description' property='og:description'/>
```

you should add a snippet in **Search Description** field while editing posts.
[image: Search Description Field]

Comment: Thanks for reply.  As I said I inserted right before tag `</head>`, thus within the head tag. Your tip is cool, but it obliges me to write all descriptions for all my past blog posts. When unavailable you may want to use `post.snippet` or `post.body`

Comment: `data:view.description` returns a snippet too even if you don't have content in **Search Description** field. just disable **description** in blog **Settings>Search preferences**.